# Is there a way to limit the amount of data that I get from a response?

Tags: node.js, axios

Hello I've got a small challenge to do where I have to display some data that I get from an api. The main page will display the first 20 results and clicking on a button will add 20 more results from the page.

The api call that I was given returns an array with around 1500 elements and the api doesn't have a parameter to limit the amount of elements in the array so my question is if I can limit it somehow with `axios` or should I just fetch all of these elements and display them?

This is the api: https://api.chucknorris.io/

Comment: can you shear the api with us?

Comment: @DanStarns Added the link in the post. I can't find anything in the documentation that can limit the amount of data i get from a call.

Answer (score 6):

there are two answers for your question

**the short answer is** :

> On your side, there's nothing you can do until pagination is implemented on API side

**the second answer is** :

> you can handle it using `http module`  like this

```
 http.request(opts, function(response) {
    var request = this;
    console.log("Content-length: ", response.headers['content-length']);
    var str = '';
    response.on('data', function (chunk) {
      str += chunk;
      if (str.length > 10000)
      {
        request.abort();
      }
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
      console.log('done', str.length);
      ...
    });
  }).end();
```

> This will abort the request at around 10.000 bytes, since the data arrives in chunks of various sizes.

Comment: Nice, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 3):

Since the API has no parameter to limit the amount of results you are responsible for modifying the response.

Since you're using Axios you *could* do this with a [response interceptor](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors) so that the response is modified before reaching your application.

You may want to consider where the best place to do this is though. If you allow the full response to come back to your application and then store it somewhere, it may be easier to return the next page of 20 results at the user's request rather than repeatedly calling the API.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm doing. I'm storing everything in an array when the app get's loaded and display just part of the array on the frontend. I guess the example with the response interceptor is probably out of the scope ofi this challenge but I will have a look. I was just worried that they might say that it is not performant to get all the data from the beginning even though the response size is around 100kb.

Comment: It's an understandable concern, but given you are limited by the API you have no choice and it sounds like you are taking the appropriate action.

Comment: Yep, that's what I imagined, I will tell the CTO my concerns regarding this issue after submitting the challenge. Thanks for clearing this up for me.